# How to show Sub Categories on Categories page?

Tags: categories

I have a product page which is assigned as category.php. Now i want to show Sub Categories as Sub Menu on the Category page. But even after searching alot i couldn't show all sub categories yet. I found one code which is :

```
 <?php
if (is_category()) {
$this_category = get_category($cat);
}
?>
<?php
if($this_category->category_parent)
$this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id
&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent.
"&echo=0"); else
$this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&depth=1
&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID.
"&echo=0");
if ($this_category) { ?> 

<ul>
<?php echo $this_category; ?>

</ul>

<?php } ?>
```

but what this is doing is it doesnt shows up the sub categories which has 0 posts. Also it shows NO CATEGORIES where categories don't have any sub categories and There is a bullet before every listing, which i dont want at all. So Please help.

Comment: You will need to use css to hide the bullets. And try setting hide_empty=false to show sub categories with 0 posts

Answer (score 3):

You can use [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) & [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) with specific  parameters (to use directly in you *category.php* template):

```
// List sub cats
$params = array(
    'parent'        =>  get_queried_object_id(), //id of current category displayed 
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    =>  false // do not hide sub cats without posts
);
if ( count( get_categories( $params ) ) ) {
    wp_list_categories( $params );
}
```

Full list of arguments can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

You can also customize the output by user your own *Walker* extending WP's [Walker_Category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/) class.

Comment: I have used wp_list_categories but in my case it wouldn't be the correct way to show categories as it lists all the category with <li> tag, so

Comment: It's not an issue as you can use the 'walker' argument in wp_list_categories and assign it a custom 'Category walker' :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/

Just create a "My_Walker_Category" (or whatever) that extends Wordpress "Walker_Category".

Then you just have to customize the rendering process in you custom walker class by overwritting the methods start_lvl, end_lvl, start_el, end_el.